Can't debug locust script with python 3.12
I'm using locust 2.29.1 for my performance tests.
It works fine on Python 3.11.8 but now I'm trying to move to Python 3.12.4 and can't debug because it's freezing on the line with import locust. Gevent compatible in PyCharm settings is checked. And I don't have any exceptions during script running.
Here is the error output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/path/to/project/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/locust/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .contrib.fasthttp import FastHttpUser
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 471, in _lock_unlock_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 365, in acquire
KeyboardInterrupt
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1551, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/path/to/project/src/scripts/locustfile.py", line 3, in <module>
    import locust
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1357, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 421, in __exit__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 376, in release
RuntimeError: cannot release un-acquired lock
python-BaseException

In the locust documentation, I didn't find any suggestions.

Are you 100% sure "gevent compatible" is actually active? because that is exactly the error message you would get if it wasnt... You can also try setting it as an env var: GEVENT_SUPPORT=True

@Cyberwiz, yes. I tried this on 2 different macOS devices and I saw the same freezing problem.

Ran into the same problem. Had to downgrade to Python 3.11.

Same issue with 3.13.1 and moving the 3.11 worked as well, 3.12 not working. Seems to be particular to the arm mac, M2 chip in my case
